# Mute a user for specific category only

Tags: discord.js

So I am making a bot which gives users the ability to be admins, but only on their own categories. So for example in 1 server there might be 3 categories - `Blue`,`Red` and `Green`.

Each made by a different user and those users can use the bot to add a specific role to other users and thus invite them to their own category.

All is well and good, but if I am in `Blue` and I get muted the mute is Server Mute. So you can't go to `Red` and be unmuted.

Usually this is fine, but since `Blue` and `Red` and `Green` have different admins and therefore different rules...being `muted` in one...doesn't mean you are breaking the rules of the other 2.

There is also an option to just remove somebody from your category by removing their role which allows them to see your category, but usually people don't want to do that. Most commonly mutes are used for when someone is playing music/ watching something and they did not mute themselves so the admin can just move them somewhere or mute them for a while.

So... using the `Server Mute` option which is granted to `ADMINISTRATORS` is not okay.

I was thinking of just adding a command to my bot `mute {category} {user}` and if you have the rights for the `category` then you can do the `mute`

So... now to my problem - how can I mute somebody but only for a specific category, and not an entire server?

Is there a way to for example make a role that has a permission override for a specific category to be muted?

Comment: Why don't you just check if the are in a channel/category that they are muted in? A possible way to achieve this might be a map of userids to an array of channels that they are muted in.

Comment: This means that everytime someone logs into a voice channel in all categories in all servers I have to call a function on my bot to check if he has to be muted in that section.

Isn't there a better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only possible way is to make a specific role that is muted in a specific channel and then assign this role to the user you wish to mute.